# Unexpected SFINAE behaviour with `std::enable_if<std::is_compound<double>::value>`

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a templated class for which I want to enable different constructors depending on the template parameter. Specifically, I want to use `std::is_compound` as a criterion.

## SSCCE

```
// bla.cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Foo{
    double bar;
public:
    template<typename U=T, 
        class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_compound<U>::value>::type
        >
    Foo(typename T::value_type& b):bar(b){}

    template<typename U=T, 
        class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_compound<U>::value>::type
        >
    Foo(T b):bar(b){}   
};

int main(){
    double d=1.0;
    Foo<std::vector<double>> f2(d); // works
    Foo<double> f1(d);          // compiler error
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

**g++ -std=gnu++11 bla.cpp**

```
bla.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class
Foo<double>’: bla.cpp:22:18:   required from here bla.cpp:11:2: error:
‘double’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3c7a78ee7cf7f54)

The problem seems to be that the first version of the constructor is being used, which fails because `double::value_type` does not exist. The problem is that that constructor shouldn't be in `Foo<double>` in the first place, because `std::is_compound<double>::value` is `false`.

Why does `std::enable_if` seem to be not working properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `typename T::value_type&`, `T` cannot be substituted by `double`. Since `T` is a template parameter of the class template and not of the constructor template, you cannot get the overload excluded by substitution failure. SFINAE only works if parameters of the template in question are involved.

If you use `typename U::value_type&`, you get a substitution failure that is not an error as `U` is a parameter of the constructor template, not of the class template.

Comment: Is it still possible to enforce that type `U` must equal type `T` in that case? It seems like any compound type would be accepted in that case? I thought the dummy parameter `U=T` would solve this for me (e.g. SFINAE would still work on `U`).

Comment: @MarcClaesen since you cannot pass explicit template arguments to constructor templates, there is no way for U to not be T.

Comment: @MarcClaesen I think what you need is `std::enable_if<std::is_compound<U>::value && std::is_constructible <T, typename U::value_type>::value>` (equally for the other constructor), but this is only enable traits like `is_constructible` for your own class `Foo`.